# Mysql join request

Tags: mysql, join

I need to get emtpy fields where data is repeated

For example an customer can have two or more contact persons, so query return (just shorted qyery resul):

**CUSTOMER_NAME| CONTACT_PERSON|ETC..**

```
  dell         |    Ighor      |etc..
  dell         |    Dima       |etc..
```

but I'm need :
**CUSTOMER_NAME| CONTACT_PERSON|etc...**

```
             dell         |    Ighor      |etc..
             NULL         |    Dima       |etc..


SELECT
             `contact`.*,
                 `branch_has_equipment`.*,
             `branch_has_contact`.*,
                         `equipment`.*,
                         `customer_has_branch`.*,
                         `branch`.*,
                         `customer`.*,
              `ip`.*

                 FROM `customer`
                 INNER JOIN `customer_has_branch`
                         ON `customer`.`customer_id` = `customer_has_branch`.`customer_id`
                 INNER JOIN `branch`
                         ON `customer_has_branch`.`branch_id` = `branch`.`branch_id`
                 INNER JOIN `branch_has_equipment`
                         ON `branch`.`branch_id` = `branch_has_equipment`.`branch_id`
                 INNER JOIN `equipment`
                         ON `branch_has_equipment`.`equipment_id` = `equipment`.`equipment_id`
                 INNER JOIN `branch_has_contact`
                         ON `branch`.`branch_id` = `branch_has_contact`.`branch_id`
                 INNER JOIN `contact`
                         ON `branch_has_contact`.`contact_id` = `contact`.`contact_id`

                INNER JOIN `equipment_has_ip`
                        ON `equipment`.`equipment_id` = `equipment_has_ip`.`equipment_id`
                INNER JOIN `ip`
                        ON `equipment_has_ip`.`equipment_id` = `ip`.`ip_id`  

                 WHERE `customer`.`inservice` = 'Yes'
                         ORDER BY `customer`.`customer_name`
```

in additional, tables ^

Customer

customer_id
customer_name
inservice
service_type
comment

Branch

branch_id
city
address

Equipment

equipment_id
brand
model
connection_param
connection_type
serial_number
id
release

Contact

contact_id
name
surname
phone_mobile
phone_work
phone_other
position

customer_has_branch_id
customer_id
branch_id

Comment: Are you sure that this is right? Looks odd to me... JOIN ip ON equipment_has_ip.equipment_id = ip.ip_id

Answer (score 0):

Since I have no idea how any of those tables relate to one another, my only answer to you is to use an `OUTER JOIN`, which will keep NULL results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seriously advocating this solution because really i think this sort of thing should be handled in application level code (e.g. a bit of PHP), but anyway, consider the following:

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +------+--------+--------+
 | game | points | player |
 +------+--------+--------+
 |    1 |      5 | Adam   |
 |    1 |      8 | Alan   |
 |    1 |      7 | Brian  |
 |    1 |      6 | John   |
 |    2 |      2 | Adam   |
 |    2 |      3 | Alan   |
 |    2 |      4 | Brian  |
 |    2 |      6 | John   |
 +------+--------+--------+

 SELECT IF(game= @prev,'',game)
      , @prev := game
   FROM my_table ORDER BY game,player;
 +-------------------------+---------------+
 | IF(game= @prev,'',game) | @prev := game |
 +-------------------------+---------------+
 | 1                       |             1 |
 |                         |             1 |
 |                         |             1 |
 |                         |             1 |
 | 2                       |             2 |
 |                         |             2 |
 |                         |             2 |
 |                         |             2 |
 +-------------------------+---------------+
```